# How can I Download my Firebase project Which is already uploaded in the firebase free domain?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I had my portfolio website hosted at the firebase free domain.
Recently I had to Format my pc due to some issues.
And Then I lost my dev. folder for the firebase website.

**Can I somehow download my firebase hosted site again ??**